# Open redis connection only for specific users, Heroku, Flask

Tags: python, flask, heroku, redis

I have a Flask webapp running on Heroku. There are functions that require more than 30 seconds to process data and for those tasks I using heroku background jobs with Redis with 20 connections limit. However, these tasks are only available for specific users.

My understanding is that Redis opens connection after I initiate the Queue, no matter if the job was queued and processed or not.

Here's my import and Queue initiation:

```
from rq import Queue
from rq.job import Job
from worker import conn as rconn

q = Queue(connection=rconn)
```

And here's my worker file:

```
import os
import urllib
from redis import Redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDIS_URL')

urllib.parse.uses_netloc.append('redis')
url = urllib.parse.urlparse(redis_url)
conn = Redis(host=url.hostname, port=url.port, db=0, password=url.password)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  with Connection(conn):
    worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
    worker.work()
```

I am looking for a way to initiate redis connection only for users with specific access level, so the app won't reach connection error.

Does it make sense to initiate Queue from `user_login` function as global variable, like this:

```
if check_password_hash(db_pwd, pwd) and acces_level==4:
    q global
    q = Queue(connection=rconn)
```

Comment: for those function queues is required, you can add a decorator which check the access level and based on that allow them to use queue

Comment: That I already have. Does Heroku count redis connection only when I add a job to the queue like this `job = q.enqueue(process_tbl)`? or when I import connection from worker and initiate `q` after imports?